# Find all 3D points inside a cube(3D Box)

Tags: c++11, vtk, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to find out the 3D points of a point cloud which are inside a 3D Box. I'm able to get the points inside 3D box by the below logic, only when the 3d box is align with the axis, but on rotating the 3d box, the logic fails.

(This only applies if the box's edges are aligned with the coordinate axes.)

If the vertices are (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y1,z1),(x1,y2,z1),⋯,(x2,y2,z2), then any point (x,y,z) is inside the box if and only if

```
x1<x<x2
and
y1<y<y2
and
z1<z<z2
```

In other words, the point's coordinates are between the vertices' coordinates.

Now I got algo from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909812/points-inside-a-3d-rectangle?noredirect=1&lq=1 but not able to figure out how to take the "position vectors".

Any suggestions!!

Another issue: Is there any fast way to find out all the points inside a 3D box, rather than iterating over the whole point cloud.

Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you listed `point-cloud-library` in the question's tags, **[pcl::CropBox](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html)** is probably what you are looking for. You basically provide the **two corner points**, a **translation** and a **rotation**, after that, you can extract all points inside the box.

Comment: Nice suggestion of CropBox. Actually I have already tried that, didn't get success so went with this mathematical approach of 3d Box's min and max vertices.

Comment: CropBox: First I draw a 3D box(ie, a vtkActor), then with the box's min(p1) and max(p7) vertices,
 I set the min-max with the respective co-ordinates, I don't get the proper points or no points at all from the cloud. image of 3D box---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/iizbo.jpg

Comment: boxFilter.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(minX, minY, minZ, 1.0));                                               
boxFilter.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(maxX, maxY, maxZ, 1.0));

Comment: I suspect something wrong with co-ordinate system (absolute-relative conflict).
 I didn't understood and found any reference what is the co-ordinate system used by setMin and setMax of CropBox...any suggestion!!

Comment: @SayanBera Can you post the code you have? There might be something wrong with your code. I can't help you without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

`I'll use the notation $\vec{OA}=\vec A-\vec O$ for a difference of position vectors. $O$ is one vertex, and $A,B,C$ are its three adjacent vertices.`

O,A,B,C in there are vertices of cuboid. Being a [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped), cube can defined by three adjacent faces, that's four points in total.